# How to get a block level element with fixed or absolute position to determine if the edges are falling off the page, and adjust?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Ok I am attempting in sorts to add an element to my existing page that would be an element that is shown above/below a button that would toggle it open/close. This elements trigger is added to several components of the page I am adding it to. In most cases showing the element when it opens below the trigger element is fine. However. There is bound to be a handful of cases where the element when toggled open will drop below the view of the page, lets say a user didnt scroll all the way down to compensate for the element opening (why would they) So for ease of use towards my users I want this element to in the event it falls out of the viewing pane to instead of opening below the trigger open above (The UI would have to change to compensate a little as well as the trigger connects to the opened box graphically in a nice fluid look, anyway that part is irrelevant, thats a bit of visual magic. Its determining if the element when opened would be outside the port or not, and if so making it load above the trigger.

Now to avoid the obvious. "What have you done". Well nothing. Making the element line up below is easy enough Ive done that before, I tend to get the triggers position, then line the element up according to the bottom of it to match based on the triggers position. So, Just trying to sort out the issue of how to handle if its out of the port even by a couple pixels make it load above the trigger. How would I compensate for something like that is the key issue, is there a particular technique I could follow or whats the "magic" if you will that I should think about when doing this?

Comment: and what if it doesn't fit even above?

Comment: Valid point, I tried to put that out of my head lol, however gaining a better understanding of how to approach it if it doesn't fit the way I want in the question, I can adjust for the problem your talking about, and in the event that it doesn't fit either direction I would likely figure something else out to load in its place or something (haven't gotten that far yet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery you can attach an handler to the [`.scroll()`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) of the document.

with that event you can always know what the visitor is viewing accessing the [`event`](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) properties `.pageX` and `.pageY`

Now you know the position of your clicked element with [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) and it's [height](http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=height&go=).

you can also get the [height](http://api.jquery.com/?ns0=1&s=height&go=) of the window object and of the element to display.

then it's only a matter of computation..

Good luck

Comment: Awesome, didn't think about the scroll handler. I think based off of what I have done with similar in the past, and a little playing around, I can get this to work smoothly off of this answer, well off to play to see if I can come up with a solution, thanks

Comment: glad to have helped. if you want (need) i can elaborate a solution, but i think you'd most like to do it on your own.

Comment: Won't ever argue with a solution, but at the same time you are right.. I prefer banging my head against the desk while coming up with a solution, more than I do one I can just copy and paste, otherwise Ill forget how to program all together and become reliant on ctrl+c, ctrl+v (or command if you've got a mac)

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this problem would be:

1. Add a container for the trigger AND the expanding/collapsing element, with `overflow:visible;` Also style the container as `position:relative;`
2. Next(obviously) style the expanding element as `position:absolute`
3. Depending on the trigger element's position relative to the screen, set the left and top properties of the expanding element, to position it above or below the trigger.